# Why is my EventListener not producing one iteration of loop?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to access only one iteration of a loop at a time based upon the element on which the eventListener is applied.  So far, I have only been able to click on it and iterate through the whole NodeList, instead of only one of them.  I would like to apply the operation to all elements of the NodeList but limit it to one element at a time.

When I take a console.log of the "hand" array onto which I am trying to push one ID of the NodeList at a time, it instead produces the entire list of all of the IDs in the NodeList.

```
function chooseCard () {
    let hand = [];
    for(const card of cards) {
        const addCard =  function () {hand.push(card.id)};
        card.addEventListener('click', addCard());
        let id1 = hand[0];
        let id2 = hand[1];
        console.log(hand);
        if(hand[0] === hand[1]) {
            addPoint();
        } else {
            changePlayer();
            if(card.id == id1 || card.id == id2) {
                card.firstElementChild.src = `img/cardback.jpeg`;
            }
            hand = [];
        }
    }
}
```

I need to see only one ID per click.

Comment: One issue is: `card.addEventListener('click', addCard());` should be `card.addEventListener('click', addCard);` - you're assigning the result of calling the function rather than using a reference of the function to `click`.

Comment: That looks like why your hand is always full. Each time you iterate though the loop, addCard() gets called in which hand.push(card.id) gets executed.

Comment: @Andy when I remove the parentheses, the appearance of all of the elements in the NodeList changes to a crumpled mess.